# echo database in write() fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","final_osa");
$sel_query="SELECT * FROM ched_scholars WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."';";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$pdf->Write( 6, 'I, echo $row["student_name"];, of legal age and a resident of echo $row["present_address"]; understand that an Educational Scholarship/Financial Grants-in Aid has been awarded to me so that I may enroll in and complete the echo $row["course"];.' );
}
```

how can I echo the student name inside the write()? thanks

Comment: it wont print the student name. it prints this one "$row["student_name"];"

Comment: You cannot echo like that in a string you need to concat it. `'string' . $var . 'more string'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: thanks i've finally made it hehe appreciate your help. i used concat

Comment: Yep, looks like that'll work now.

Comment: I've rollbacked your inclusion of the solution in the question itself (you may find it in the revision history). Instead, please post it as its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use "{$var}" inside your string:

For example:

```
$myVar = "student";
$myString = "The {$myVar} are good.";
```

In your case:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","final_osa");
$sel_query="SELECT * FROM ched_scholars WHERE id = '".$_GET['id']."';";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$pdf->Write( 6, 'I, {$row["student_name"]}, of legal age and a resident of {$row["present_address"]} understand that an Educational Scholarship/Financial Grants-in Aid has been awarded to me so that I may enroll in and complete the {$row["course"]}.' );
}
```